# Image, content and arrow in the div

Tags: html, css

Please help me make this div look just like the image below. 
I try to make this work but it seems I was missing something please help me make my code more accurate. I tried to research but i can't find the solution. Hope someone could help me on this.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left-width: 4px;
  font: bold 22px/100px Arial, Sans-Serif;
  color: black;
}

#mybtn1 {
  position: relative;
  font: bold 12px/50px Arial, Sans-Serif;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -210px;
  left: 110px;
  float: right;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: ;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mybtn1:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

#div1 {
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

#div1 img {
  height: 400px;
}

#mybtn1 img {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto 10px;
}

#mybtn1 h1,
#mybtn1 p {
  margin-left: 140px;
  /* = image width + 8 */
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

#mybtn1 h1 {
  left: 50px;
}


}
```

```html
<html>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <img src="rice.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div id="mybtn1">
        <h1>Title </h1>
        <img src="logo1.png" />
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. R</p>
        <svg class="icon-arrow" viewBox="0 0 137.648 256">
    <polygon class="line" points="0,246.161 9.843,256 137.648,128.2 137.451,128.003 137.648,127.806 9.843,0 0,9.833 118.167,127.996 " style="stroke-width:2"></polygon>
    </svg>
      </div </li>
      <ul>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You didn't include the image.

Comment: Its say's that i cant put an image so please check this http://www.polymtl.ca/gch/sites/gch.amigow.polymtl.ca/files/anglais_mars_2017-100_1.jpg . The logo will be in on the left, center is the text and the arrow is the right corner (the sample image don't have arrow) hope you got the idea.  Hope you could help me. thanks!

Comment: Please include the image in your answer, links are also okay if you do not yet have the privilege to post an image. You can do so by **editing** your question :)

Comment: @ zabura http://www.polymtl.ca/gch/sites/gch.amigow.polymtl.ca/files/anglais_mars_2017-100_1.jpg this is the sample img for what i want to my div id="mybtn1". I just want to have the div id="mybtn1" to arrange logo on the left text on the center and the arrow will be on the right inside that div. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid syntax in the codes, Fix it by this:

```
<li>
  <div id="mybtn1">
    <h1>Title </h1>
    <img src="logo1.png" />
    <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. R</p>
    <svg class="icon-arrow" viewBox="0 0 137.648 256">
      <polygon class="line" points="0,246.161 9.843,256 137.648,128.2 137.451,128.003 137.648,127.806 9.843,0 0,9.833 118.167,127.996 " style="stroke-width:2"></polygon>
    </svg>
  </div>
</li>
```